# Dynamic height vertical line component for use as a flexbox child and non-flexbox child

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to create a component that I can insert as a vertical line between flex box columns. I need the height to be dynamic. I am setting the `height=100%` and setting `align-self: stretch`(because the flexbox  is a row). Nothing is happening. The div gets a height of 0

---

This is the component

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default styled.div`

    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    height: 100%;
    align-self: stretch;
    width: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;

`
```

And this is how I inject it

```
      <VerticalLine></VerticalLine>
```

---

If I add some content to the component, then the line is only as tall as the content

```
      <VerticalLine>a</VerticalLine>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the height, because flex is adjusting the height by themself:

```
.verticalLine {
  border-left: 3px solid gray;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

See my example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbx8mzk0/1/)

Comment: It doesn't look like that changed anything. I updated my question to include those 2 properties though

Comment: Do you want to give the border a height of 100?  change 100% to 50px it will work.

Comment: I know that will work but I need the height to be dynamic

Comment: ok remove 100% because flex is adjusting the height. see: https://jsfiddle.net/fbx8mzk0/1/

Comment: Thanks, you actually don't need `width: 1px` or `display: block`. It works the same without them. Is there any way to make the class work more use cases, like when this component isn't a child of a component styled with flex?

Comment: Yes but is better to define a width. This will work for flex styling. What do you mean with isn't a child? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm trying to create a reuseable component. Right now this component will only work properly if it's parent is styled using flex. I might want to place this component inside a parent that is not styled using flex, see: https://jsfiddle.net/hL7bpr4s/8/

Comment: use `display: inline;` instead of block, see https://jsfiddle.net/d7bn8euq/1/